# microsoft graph creating planner after creating group

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api, office365api, beta

Im trying to create planner with the graph api

the goal was to

1. take in planner name from user
2. create office group thru API
3. add current user as owner/member
4. create planner with the newly created group.

However I cant seem to create planner right after the group is created.

Get Client Auth Token -> Create Group (successful) -> Group Owner automatically set to user (token owner) -> Add Current user as member (successful) -> create planner (error - 403)

```
{ "error": { "code": "UnknownError", "message": "", "innerError": { "request-id": "---------------------------", "date": "2017-01-19T17:16:11" } } }
```

however if i wait up to 3 minute-ish after the group is created and make the same call that was erroring (creating planner), it will create planner without a problem.

is the api not possible to create planner right after the group is created?

I really dont want to have to make the user wait there for minutes until the planner gets created.

any thoughts would be greatly helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the Group being the foundational component here, you cannot provision resources tied to that Group until that Group is fully provisioned. I would look at the *create group* step as asynchronous so you'll need to hold all dependent anyone until that completes.